# CustomTag is undefined while creating custom Polymer component

Tags: dart, polymer

I am trying to create custom element using the following:

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

// Custom elements extend PolymerElement
@CustomTag('my-element')
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
 // custom functionality goes here
}
```

Dart Editor shows error 'Undefined name CustomTag

I am trying the example given at the URL below. All files are copied as listed at the URL below.

https://github.com/sethladd/dart-polymer-dart-examples/blob/master/web/custom_element_that_contains_other_tags/my_element.dart

Am I missing something in pubspec? pubspec is not listed at the above URL.

Comment: Are you definitely on Polymer 0.5.2 or later? I saw a post by Siggi around the time of your post where he released a new update to Polymer that included fixes related to the new syntax. Please try a Pub Update and Reanalyze Sources to see if there are fixes for you to pick up.

Comment: that was the problem. Thanks.